# I am using PIL to transfer large HDF file to tiff stack, but encounter code problem

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I used the following code to transfer big HDF file to a tiff stack. It works fine with small number of images (less than 348 slices). But I encounter problems. Please give some help on this problem.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

filename = 'Rec_frame_00007.hdf' 

"""
The file name would be modified to satisfy the input fil name input. 

"""

f = h5py.File(filename,'r')

a = f.get('entry')
b = a.get('data')
c = b.get('data')
d = np.array(c)

"""
The range needs to be modified to reflect how many slices are in the hdf file 

"""
im = []
r = d.shape[0]
for i in range(r):
    #name = 'figure'+str(i)+'.tif'
    im.append(Image.fromarray(d[i]))
#%%  
im[0].save("scann42.tif",save_all=True,append_images = im[0:])
```

The error is as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "hdf2tifmodified.py", line 29, in <module>
    im[0].save("scann42.tif",save_all=True,append_images = im[0:])   File "/opt/apps/apps/binapps/anaconda3/2019.03/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1994, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)   File "/opt/apps/apps/binapps/anaconda3/2019.03/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1843, in _save_all
    tf.newFrame()   File "/opt/apps/apps/binapps/anaconda3/2019.03/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1667, in newFrame
    self.finalize()   File "/opt/apps/apps/binapps/anaconda3/2019.03/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1661, in finalize
    self.writeLong(IFDoffset)   File "/opt/apps/apps/binapps/anaconda3/2019.03/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1754, in writeLong
    bytesWritten = self.f.write(struct.pack(self.longFmt, value)) struct.error: 'L' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
```

Comment: is your value larger than 4.29... GB? 4GiB... the max that you can fit in a 32bit number seems to be what it is barking about...

Comment: Hi, Yes. The image is 15 GB.

Comment: Do  you know a way to transfer a big tiff file?

Comment: Tiff's use 32bit fields, you can't have a 15GB tiff... if you are dealing with uncompressed data perhaps you can tile them 2X2 that would be close, but probably ok... as in quadrant 1 is one image quadrant 2 is one image ...

Comment: Hi Grady, if the file is divided into several tiffs, finally they need to be combined into one. So the same problem is still there.

Comment: So now, I used Fiji to transfer the HDF5 to tiffs. It works fines. But sometimes it will be forced quit. Maybe the file is too large.

Comment: 15 doesn't fit into 4... the format itself has 32 bit values if I understand correctly... so it just can't be done, you can't have a 15GiB TIFF... someone has tried to extend it: https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/bigtiff.html I dont know if this is in use anywhere.